# Serial Port application not working with exported executable jar

Tags: java, swing, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am unable to run an application, one of the functions of which is to show the serial ports and i can run the application in Netbeans but can't do the same when I try to run it in an exported executable jar, I don't know what's causing the problem, I already have the necessary serial comm files in the right places, I really need help guys..

I tried using the java -jar filename.jar and this is what I got :-

```
C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\NetBeansProjects\drdoProject\dist>java -jar drdoProject.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier
    at drdoproject.GridMap.showPorts(GridMap.java:315)
    at drdoproject.GridMap.showPortsActionPerformed(GridMap.java:371)
    at drdoproject.GridMap.access$700(GridMap.java:26)
    at drdoproject.GridMap$2.actionPerformed(GridMap.java:204)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: do this: java -jar <yourJarFile> in a terminal, an exception will come out for sure... try to post its content here so we can make a diagnostic

Comment: there it is, you can have a look

Comment: is this class in the project CommPortIdentifier

Comment: yes that it is, i have included the comm.jar library in my project, well this works fine in netbeans but not in the exported jar

Comment: I'd expect NetBans to put any required JAR or lib in the `dist`  directory when you build the project.

Comment: The Jar containing `CommPortIdentifier` is not on the run-time class-path of the executable Jar.

Comment: yeah then I think netbeans do it automatically by itself, what to do?

Comment: any ideas on what is happening?